# placing pin points on google maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, cordova

I want to place pin points on a google map.But the problem is i have so many locations to pin point and the way i'm doing it is a bit difficult.Is there a easy way to do this?

The way i'm doing it

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile, $state) {
      function initialize() {

        //variables for adding the coordinates of the locations

        var Chunnakam = new google.maps.LatLng(9.741527 ,80.033931);
        var Nelliady = new google.maps.LatLng( 9.828288,80.220362);
        var Karaditoku_Kilinochchi = new google.maps.LatLng(9.380289,80.377);
        //alot more of these come after this
```

ANd i'm placing the points like this

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: Chunnakam,
          map: map,
          title: 'Chunnakam'
        });

        var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: Nelliady,
          map: map,
          title: 'Nelliady'
        });

//
        var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: Karaditoku_Kilinochchi,
          map: map,
          title: 'Karaditoku Kilinochchi'
        });
```

Is there a easy way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array of objects and iterate over that:

```
var towns = [ { marker: null, name: 'Chunnakam', lat: 9.741527, lng: 80.033931 },
              { marker: null, name: 'Nelliady', lat: 9.828288, lng: 80.220362 },
              // add new towns here
            ];


angular.forEach(towns, function(town) {
    town.marker =  new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(town.lat, town.lng),
        map: map,
        title: town.name
    });
}
```